# How do I print the array contents for a random insertion sort along with the words before the random number?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

This code sorts and prints the random numbers which are what I want. What I am missing is the words that go before the numbers. I am new to java but am more proficient in Python. I want each random number when printed out to say the following:

result[0] = _

result[1] = _

result[2] = _

result[3] = _

Without having to put each of these in the code one by one.
In Python, the code would be the following which would print all of it out.

`print(“result[“,I,”] =“, result[I])`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Size of Random Number");
        int n = input.nextInt(); 
        Random random = new Random(); 
        int[] result = random.ints(n, -n, n).toArray();
        
        Arrays.stream(result).forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("\n");
        
       
        int len = result.length;
        System.out.println("Insertion Sort");
        for(int i=1; i<len; i++){
            int j;
            int key = result[i];
            for (j=i-1; (j >= 0 && result[j] > key); j--) { 
                result[j + 1] = result[j]; 
                result[j+1] = key;
                for( i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    System.out.println("result[" + (i) + "] =" );
                    Arrays.stream(result).forEach(System.out::println);
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }  
            } 
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have put the print statement inside the nested loop. Also, you are printing the whole array on each iteration of the nested loop. Just take that out and print only one element in one iteration.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Size of Random Number: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] result = random.ints(n, -n, n).toArray();

        Arrays.stream(result).forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("\n");

        // Insertion sort
        int len = result.length;
        for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
            int key = result[i];
            int j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && result[j] > key) {
                result[j + 1] = result[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            result[j + 1] = key;
        }

        System.out.println("After sorting: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.println("result[" + (i) + "] =" + result[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter Size of Random Number: 5
0
-5
-3
2
1


After sorting: 
result[0] =-5
result[1] =-3
result[2] =0
result[3] =1
result[4] =2
```

**Note:** I've also corrected your sorting logic. There are hundreds of tutorials available on the internet to learn about Insertion Sort e.g. you can check [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/).

Comment: Thank you. If I were to change it from largest to smallest, what would I need to change?

Comment: You are most welcome. For descending order, simply change the condition to `result[j] < key` keeping everything else as it is. Feel free to comment in case of any other doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for(i = 0; i < result.len; i++){
    System.out.println("result[" + i + "] = " + result[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can change it so it can sort using the insertion. This doesn't do any sorting necessarily. Do I need to put the system.out.println inside of the for loop that does the sorting?

Comment: Yes, the innermost for loop has to be replaced with this for loop if you want to print out the result for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to replace this line: `System.out.println("result[" + (i) + "] =" );`

for this line: `System.out.println("result[" + (i) + "] =" + result[i]);`

or you can use `String.format`:

`System.out.println(String.format("result[%d] = %s", i, result[i]));`

You have to remove also the other two lines:

```
// here you are printing again all the numbers so is not necessary
Arrays.stream(result).forEach(System.out::println); 

// here you are adding another linebreak, but using println add the linebreak automatically
System.out.println("\n");
```